# why \s+ do not match the space in macro with grep?

Tags: regex, shell, grep

i want to search the define of macro of   `ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX`  ,

so i run the command

```
 grep   "define\s+ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX" -r  ./
```

but it find nothing .

So,I try

```
grep   "define\s*ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX" -r  ./
```

it success return the define of `ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX`,it return

```
./Zend/zend_API.h:#define ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX  ....
```

## My problem :

why  `\s+` do not match the space in macro ?

I think it should match at least one space .

Comment: `\s` is ERE synatx.

Comment: @Cyrus, not ERE but PCRE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- `\s` is PCRE syntax. `grep` supports BRE (by default) or ERE (when called as `egrep` or passed the `-E` argument), but not PCRE absent nonstandard extensions. Use `[[:space:]]` instead.
- `+` is ERE syntax, whereas by default `grep` uses BRE. Either pass `-E` to grep, or invoke it as `egrep`, to enable ERE.

Thus:

```
grep -Ere "define[[:space:]]+ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX" ./
```

Comment: GNU's implementation of `grep` supports `\s` as an extension. This is allowed by POSIX.

Comment: @hvd, allowed but not required, so it's by no means safe to rely on. And you sure that's part of grep, not part of glibc? If the latter, this isn't reliably available even on GNU grep, depending on the current platform. (It's *certainly* libc-provided in bash's `[[ $var =~ $regex ]]` builtin).

Comment: Yes, but because the OP's implementation does accept it, this fails to answer the question. The problem the OP is having is due to `+` matching a literal plus sign in BRE. As for your edited comment, not sure if it's part of grep or glibc.

Comment: Ahh; I skimmed over the question a little too quickly there. Amended.

Answer (score 3):

The *standard* grep that comes with Linux does not accept `+`, only `*`. You could put it like this:

```
grep "define\s\s*ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX" -r ./
```

or this

```
grep -E "define\s+ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX" -r ./
```

Comment: `grep -E` is certainly part of the [POSIX standard for `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html). Perhaps the words "by default" should be added? And ignoring that `\s` isn't guaranteed by the standard either is quite an oversight.

Comment: Amended. BTW what version of grep doesn't support `\s` nowadays?

Comment: The first that comes to mind is busybox.  That said, `\s` wasn't a documented feature of even GNU grep until 2010.

Comment: (Of course, busybox uses the platform's regex engine, so what syntax it supports depends on which libc it's compiled against).