# Unix command to grep only a substring starting with "xyz...." up to the first space?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have a text:

This is my=test and class=76

This is my=test and class=78

This is my=test2 and class=76

This is my=test3 and class=75

This is my=test1 and class=79.

I want to grep all the word starting with "class=" with the values without printing the whole line the output should be:

```
class=76
class=78
class=76
class=75
class=79
```

any command that can help me on this?

I tried this :

```
grep -E '(^|\s+)class=(?=\s|$)' file
```

but was not getting any output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can grep show only words that match search pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546711/can-grep-show-only-words-that-match-search-pattern)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965192/why-s-do-not-match-the-space-in-macro-with-grep

Answer (score 5):

Your `(^|\s+)class=(?=\s|$)` pattern is not POSIX compliant because it contains a positive lookahead `(?=\s|$)` that is meant to match a location that is followed with a whitespace or end of string position. As you want to match digits right after `class=`, this lookahead makes no sense even in a PCRE regex. The `(^|\s+)` group is meant to match start of string or 1 or more whitespaces, but it seems a mere word boundary will do here.

You may use

```
grep -oE '\<class=[^ ]+' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/53UoV8)

**Details**

- `o` - enables the output mode, only outputs matches
- `E` - enables POSIX ERE syntax
- `\<` - a word boundary (also `\b` can be used instead)
- `class=` - a literal string
- `[^ ]+` - 1 or more chars other than space

Equivalent BRE POSIX version:

```
grep -o '\<class=[^ ]*' file
```

Tested with *grep (GNU grep) 2.27*.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked,Now, lets say i want to get the string after "class=" but before the first space occurence. Then what would be the modified command?

Comment: `grep -oE '\<class=[^[:space:]]+' file`. Or `\S+`, or `[^ ]+`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl-oneliner

```
> data="This is my=test and class=76 This is my=test and class=78 This is my=test2 and \n class=76 This is my=test3 and class=75 This is my=test1 and class=79."
> perl -0777 -ne ' { while(/(class=(\d+))/g) { print "$1\n" } } ' <<< "$data"                                                                                   
class=76
class=78
class=76
class=75
class=79
>
```

Works, even if you have the data in a file

```
> echo "$data" > gupta.txt
> perl -0777 -ne ' { while(/(class=(\d+))/g) { print "$1\n" } } ' gupta.txt 
class=76
class=78
class=76
class=75
class=79
>
```